# Tem como salvar e carregar arquivo texto em uma iframe ou no openWYSIWYG?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Gostei bastante do código para salvar e carregar texto na `textarea` de um post aqui. Porém gostaria de saber se tem algum código parecido para fazer a mesma função com uma `iframe` em vez de `textarea` ou que funcione corretamente na textarea do openWYSIWYG. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria imensamente.

Vocês podem ver um exemplo do que estou querendo fazer nesse [**link**](http://www.letrasdigitais.com.br/Editor/example.html).

Tentei improvisar o código completo abaixo no openWYSIWYG que é textarea e também não funciona. Alguém sabe pq?

```
function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
  ...
  function loadFileAsText() {
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();  ...
```

Comment: Porque você quer fazer em um iframe exatamente?

Comment: Por favor, coloque o link do código que menciona. Melhor ainda, coloque seu prórprio código já modificado. É só [edit] a pergunta.

Comment: Porque estou tentando criar um editor de texto simples em html e javascript para aplicar na escola e com uma textarea eu não consegui fazer os comandos de tipo de letra, tamanho, cor da letra e justificar parágrafos funcionarem no firefox. Consegui baixar um código que realiza isso perfeitamente porém em uma iframe. É que sou meio leigo no assunto sabe!!!

Comment: @JoséPaulo Se precisar de ajuda para fazer isso funcionar no CKEditor, sugiro fazer uma nova pergunta e postar o código que tentou, incluindo o trecho de HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Desculpe se minha resposta não vai diretamente ao requisito da pergunta, mas acredito que a abordagem não está correta.

## openWYSIWYG

Pesquisei um pouco sobre o [openWYSIWYG](http://www.openwebware.com/) e parece que o projeto não é mantido há alguns anos. O primeiro sinal ocorreu quanto tentei abrir no meu Chrome e surgiu um popup dizendo que meu navegador não é suportado. Tentei abrir no Firefox e as imagens não carregaram.

**Não recomendo usar este editor**.

## `iframe`

Usar um `iframe` para conseguir formatação não é necessário diretamente. Basta usar um editor WYSIWYG que funcione e faça o trabalho por você.

## TinyMCE

Existem vários editores, mas o que tenho um pouco mais familiaridade é o [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Veja um [exemplo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Para carregar e salvar o conteúdo sendo editado você pode usar, respectivamente, os métodos [getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) e [setContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent).

## CKEditor

Outra alternativa popular, mas que nunca cheguei a usar, é o [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo).

Um exemplo simples ([extraído da documentação](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```